# Change Spotfire Document Properties value using javascript

Tags: javascript, properties, document, tibco, spotfire

I want to Change the value assigned to a Document Property in spot fire. Lets say i have created a new document property called "Test1" as a string and assign it a value "a". Is there are way to change this value using Javascript every time i load the spotfire dashboard ?

Comment: If the answer below worked for the question posted, please accept it or add any clarifying comments you need :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of a way to use JavaScript for this, but you can assign a `string` document property via custom expression (if it's a List Box) or run an IronPython script each time the value changes. So, you could set the expression to the current date, `datetimenow()` and then every time it's loaded the IronPython script would fire. However, I don't see why you'd need the property control for this.

I suppose it really depends on what you want the document property to be set to. Is it data from your tables? Output from complex code? These are all things to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So i want to run an ironpython script whenever the vizualization is loading . I am new to spotfire. i saw some links online where people are discussing this issue but i am not able to replicate the same solution at my end. So the idea i had was that somehow i will trigger the javascript whenever the dashboard is loading where i will change the document property which i have created which will eventually run the iron python code. Please let me know if you can help in this matter

Comment: it sounds like the question you've asked here is not the question you need answered. my suggestion is to close this question and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create an input type property control using the Document Property you want to change.

2) Edit Html to assign parent element an id say "testInput". And add the script as shown below in the Edit HTML window.

```
<span id="testInput"><SpotfireControl id="7db34e6c423240f59fc99e6b80fa23ec" /></span>


<script>
$("#testInput input").val("after");
$("#testInput input").focus();
$("#testInput input").blur();
</script>
```

3) This script will change the document property value to "after" whenever you open a file.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, I'm using Spotfire 7.8.

Answer (score 0):

As you comment seemed to suggest, something you can do is write this code in Python and attach the script to an action control, e.i. a Link or a Button.  Something simple like: `Document.Properties["Test1"] = newValue`
or even: `Document.Properties[changingProperty] = newValue`
allowing the code to be more reusable.

Then you insert Javascript into the Text Area as well to the effect of: `$("#VeryLongSpotfireControlID").click();`

Which should simulate clicking on action control, which in turn triggers the Python script to update the value.  Just be careful not to use this approach when it would result in reloading the text area HTML, as this will re-trigger the Javascript, thus creating an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a possible solution/work-around for the issue, entirely based on pure JavaScript (since TIBCO removed jQuery starting from Spotfire X). The solution is to force a simulated Enter Keystroke while focusing the input box to trigger updating the Document Property. (No data function and R needed)

HTML (SpotfireControl Element is an single line input-box for a Doc. Prop.):

```
<div id="container"><SpotfireControl id="b8534f13dc62416db6d4eaab16030f5e" /></div>
```

JS (focus and blur might no longer be needed for this solution, but I'm still keeping them just in case):

```
const inputConfirmationEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {
    keyCode: 13,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false
});

var elem = document.querySelector("#container input");
elem.value = "stringValue";
elem.blur();
elem.focus();

document.querySelector("#container input").dispatchEvent(inputConfirmationEvent);
```

Hope it helps someone.

Best,
Aaron